# JS expression for a function with a property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to write a single expression in ES6 for a function that also has a property?

i.e. is there a simpler way to write the expression after `f=` without the wrapper?

```
f = (function(){
  const f = function(x) { return 2*x; };
  f.foo = 'bar';
  return f;
})();
```

Comment: What is the wrapper doing? The returned value isn't used so the code shown has no net effect. What's wrong with just having the first two lines `const f = ...` and `f.foo = ...` on their own?

Comment: It returns a function that has a property. For the question it doesn't matter how the expression will be used, but I'm looking for a simpler way to write the expression.

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean, but I think the question would be clearer if the result was shown to be used in some way.

Comment: Just having those two lines will not do in a case where I'm constructing an object and one of its properties is that function, e.g. `obj = {foo: 42, bar: 'baz', func: ??? };` In place of the ??? I need an expression, that's why the wrapper is there

Comment: @nnnnnn The "single expression" is the important part.

Comment: Why not just create a reusable function that takes a couple arguments that does what you want and you can call it any time you need it?  I don't get the use of an IIFE here.

Comment: What about `{..., func: g}` where `g` is defined using the 2 lines?

Comment: @travelboy - Yes, I understand why you want an expression. But a little context rarely hurts. I'm saying if the question provided an example (the object construction example in your comment is an excellent example) then the question would be clearer and this whole discussion would have been avoided. Also the answer that basically said "don't wrap the lines" wouldn't have been posted. So...

Comment: @nnnnnn: I edited the question so the return value is being used in some way. Hopefully it's clearer that way.

Comment: Btw, you cannot *declare* a function in an *expression* :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Object.assign(function(x) { return 2 * x }, {foo: 'bar'})
```

would do it.

Answer (score 0):

As nnnnnn's comment suggests, the IIFE wrapper doesn't seem to be accomplishing anything.

```
const f = (function(){
  const f = function(x) { return 2*x; };
  f.foo = 'bar';
  return f;
})();
```

is the same as

```
const f = function(x) { return 2*x; };
f.foo = 'bar';
```

and I think using `Object.assign` just obfuscates what is going on above.

Comment: But the question is about specifically doing it as an expression, not statements.

Comment: I don't see the need, but sure.